# Как использовать for в react

Tags: reactjs

Есть компонент, который принимает число и отрисовывает соответствующее количество звездочек.

Делаю так, что не очень-то удобно и довольно грустно.

```
function Stars({count}) {
  let star = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      star.push(i)
  }

  let items = star.map(item => <li key={item}><Star /></li>);

  return <ul>{items}</ul>;
}
```

Хочу сделать так:

```
function Stars({count}) {
  let items = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      items += <li key={i}><Star /></li>;
  }

  return <ul>{items}</ul>;
}
```

Да только получаю `null[object Object]` вместо звездочек.

Как в `react` реализовать ту логику, которую я хочу или максимально упростить первый вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбирай:

```
function Stars({count}) {
  let star = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    star.push(i)
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {star.map(item => <li key={item}><Star /></li>)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

```
function Stars({count}) {
  let items = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    items.push(<li key={i}><Star /></li>);
  }

  return <ul>{items}</ul>;
}
```

```
function Stars({count}) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {Array(count).fill().map((x,i) => <li key={i}><Star /></li>)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!